# auto login via c# webBrowser, on a javascript based site

Tags: c#, javascript

Ive been trying to auto login to a javascript based site using a c# webBrowser form,
after a bit of searching I came up with how to auto fill the username and password:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email Id").InnerText = "email";
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password Id").InnerText = "password";
```

but I just couldnt find how to auto click the "enter" button.
ive tried using the same method as the auto fill with the invoke option:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn").InvokeMember("click");
```

but it didnt work, so here's some of the site's source code 
(a small prtion, showing the login form section)

```
</a>
<form id="login" name="login" action="index.php?sendPass=true" method="post" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; position: relative">
    <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 0; padding-top: 0;">

    <div style="font: 12px arial; margin: 0; text-align: center"></div>
        <img src="new1/login_title_ido.jpg" alt="" />
    <div style="margin:0px; margin-bottom:10px">
    <div style="font: 12px arial; margin: 0px">דוא"ל &nbsp;:
    <input type="text" name="email" class="loginInput" value="" dir="ltr" /></div>
    <div style="font: 12px arial; margin-top: 1px">סיסמה:
    <input type="password" name="pass" class="loginInput" style="margin-right:1px;margin-top:1px" value="" dir="ltr" /></div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick="alert('הכנס דואר אלקטרוני&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; \n ולחץ על כפתור הכנס&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');"><u>שכחתי סיסמה</u></a>
    <input type="image" src="new/login.jpg" align="middle" style="margin-right: 25px;" />
    </div>
    <div style="color: #000000; padding-top:3px; direction:rtl">
          </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

I just cant seem to pinpoint the "enter" button id, any ideas?! or perhaps theres other ways to invoke the "enter" button?

Answer (score 0):

You are simulating click event correctly, but I don't see any input on the form with id="btn".
Simply try to add it in your markup like this:

```
<input id="btn" type="image" src="new/login.jpg" align="middle" style="margin-right: 25px;" />
```

EDIT:
If you don't have access to source you could try something like this:

```
var forms = webBrowser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("login");
var form = forms[forms.Count - 1];
if(form.TagName.Equals("FORM"))
{
   form.InvokeMember("Submit");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "changing my markup"? just to clearfy this is not my site im just trying to logon automaticly via c# form..

Comment: iv'e tried implementing it but there's an error, it says that theres no TagName function in HtmlElementCollection

Comment: it because I getting several forms, try to add var form = forms[forms.Count - 1]; as I wrote in updated version.